# Typing for QTable @request

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I tried to implement "[Server side pagination, filter and sorting sample](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#server-side-pagination-filter-and-sorting)" in Typescript.

I used `QTableProps['onRequest']` for props typing but it doesn't work:

```
function onRequest (props: QTableProps['onRequest']) {
   console.log(props);
}
```

This is the error that TS reported:

```
Type '(props: ((requestProp: { pagination: { sortBy: string; descending: boolean; page: number; rowsPerPage: number; }; filter: (rows: readonly any[], terms: any, cols?: readonly any[] | undefined, getCellValue?: ((col: any, row: any) => any) | undefined) => readonly any[]; getCellValue: (col: any, row: any) => any; }) =>...' is not assignable to type '(requestProp: { pagination: { sortBy: string; descending: boolean; page: number; rowsPerPage: number; }; filter: (rows: readonly any[], terms: any, cols?: readonly any[] | undefined, getCellValue?: ((col: any, row: any) => any) | undefined) => readonly any[]; getCellValue: (col: any, row: any) => any; }) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'requestProp' are incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found that the problem can be solved by using [Parameters and NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html).

```
export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    onRequest(
      props: Parameters<NonNullable<QTableProps['onRequest']>>[0]
    ) {
      // The rest of code
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide a bit more detail on exactly how you are doing this..
Here is an example of how i would achieve the same..

Hope it helps.

```
<q-table @request="onRequest"/>

import type  { QTableProps } from "quasar";

const onRequest: QTableProps['onRequest'] => ({pagination, filter, getCellValue}) =>{
//... your code here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is close to what I need. But I am thinking to use the method with Options API. Can you help me with this? In fact I need typing the method inside object literal.